# wordpress functions works on localhost only but not on websites

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I need to get edit and delete links after publishing the post
I test my code on localhost server and it works well
but when I test on my website it gets permalink only

```
<?php
require('../wp-load.php');

$my_post = [
  'post_title'    => 'Hello',
  'post_content'  => 'Hello world.' ,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => [ 1 ]
];

$ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

$permalink = get_permalink($ID);
$editlink = get_edit_post_link($ID);
$dellink = get_delete_post_link($ID);

echo $permalink.'<br>';
echo $editlink.'<br>';
echo $dellink.'<br>';

?>
```

where is the problem please ?

Comment: Are you logged into wordpress? It won't return the link if you are not connected.

Comment: of course I'm logged into wordpress, I get the permalink only but not edit and delete links !

Comment: Those functions won't return urls if the current user does not have permissions to do the action themselves. Make sure your user can edit the post (current_user_can( 'edit_post', $ID )). If this returns false, then you won't get either links. The action is 'delete_post' for the delete link.

Comment: 'post_author'   => 1, is the admin user but no edit/delete links!

Comment: Can you check the value of `$ID`. If it's `0` then it means there was an error

Comment: in all sites I can get the permalink which is based on plain structure (http://www.mysite.comcom/?p=123) so the post ID is get a value properly

Comment: I've correct logging code into wp then it succeeded and get all links :) but if I click on delete link it shows as The link you followed has expired.!

Comment: here is logging code: $user_login = 'ptmw'; 
$user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
$user_id = $user->ID; 
wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); 
do_action('wp_login', $user_login);